# Main Camera is resetting its position in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm new to 3D game development and I'm trying to make a 3D game in Unity v2019.4.39f1.

I'm facing a problem with the main camera's position.

I made the main camera to be a child of a game object so that it follows it. This is the hierarchy of the main camera.

[Main Camera Heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzVkY.png)

I initially set the position of the camera as shown in the figure.

[Transform before starting the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irzOg.png)

But during the gameplay, the main camera's position is always reset to the one shown in the following figure.

[Transform after starting the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4nP6.png)

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: Let me guess, the CameraShake is resetting the position on Update?

Comment: Nope. I just tried disabling it but nothing changed.